# How can I find the potential energy and force between a steel sphere and a magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, energy, magnetic-fields, potential-energy

I'm fine with certain simplifying assumptions being made, I currently only know high-school level physics (the simpler the better). Also, if anyone can explain the intuition behind formulae, I would appreciate it.